# Showing "Done" button in IOS InAppBrowser with Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm using Phonegap 3.3 to develop an iOS app and trying to get the InAppBrowser working with a "Done" button so the user can return to the app once they're done on the external page. The link looks like this:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://someurl.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');">http://someurl.com</a>
```

I ran `phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git` to add the plugin. The browser itself seems to be working, but I can't get the location toolbar to show up, so there's no way to exit once it's open. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that somehow the line to include `phonegap.js` had been removed from index.html. Adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>` solved the problem.

Comment: I'm confused as to where the <script> tag would be included - within myapp/www/index.html or someurl.com/index.html ?

Comment: I registered it just after the end of the content in my `<body>` tag in myapp/www/index.html, so it ended up looking something like `<html><head>...</head><body>...<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>...</body></html>`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>` solved this issue for me as well. Also, please note that I am using a Yeoman generator (Cordova), which is a great way to get up and running; however, the **phonegap.js** include script was not referenced in the html file, so be sure to check for it.